# How to log data from ELMAH NuGet to MySQL database?

Tags: model-view-controller, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have a problem with elmah.mysql NuGet. I install it, I run the script in phpmyadmin ( the table and procedures are added ) but it says that the scheme elmah hasn`t been found.